# Criar página (page) somente no código PHP do WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Como criar uma *page* somente pelo código? Pois ela é estática, ou seja, não precisa de inserir conteúdo pelo painel, mas para ter a URL dessa página, é preciso criar um página, mesmo que ela fique em branco, sem conteúdo. O que eu preciso é ter essa page apenas no código.

Ex `page-estatico.php`:

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>

<main>
    <h1> ESTÁTICO </h1>
    <h3>Página criada somente no código</h3>
</main>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Já escrevi plugins que fazem coisas semelhantes mas usando um template dentro da pasta do próprio plugin e interceptando com `template_redirect`. Acreditava que tinha algo parecido já escrito mas não achei. Fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei [Virtual Page Within Theme Template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17978666/1287812) e até publiquei a mesma solução lá na hora de interceptar o `parse_request`.

Inclui-se uma nova `rewrite_rule` com o endereço virtual e ao conferir o *request*, se for o endereço virtual, imprimir uma simulação de template e interromper o resto da execução.

Instale o plugin e clique <kbd>Atualizar</kbd> nas opções de Permalinks (`/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`). Depois, visite: `http://example.com/virtual`. O ideal é registrar um `flush_rewrite_rules` na ativação e desativação, mas nos meus testes não está funcionando na desativação do plugin, então prefiro sugerir a atualização manual.

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Página virtual
 */

add_action( 'init', 'init_sopt_38020' );
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'query_vars_sopt_38020' );
add_action( 'parse_request', 'parse_request_sopt_38020');

function init_sopt_38020() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'virtual/?', 'index.php?virtual=new', 'top' );
}

function query_vars_sopt_38020( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'virtual';
    return $query_vars;
}

function parse_request_sopt_38020( $wp ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'virtual', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        get_header(); ?>
        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">
                Olá, mundo!
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php get_footer();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo do uso que você terá para o arquivo `page-estatico.php`, pode ser criado um template de página de Wordpress, colocando no início do arquivo `page-estatico.php` o seguinte código:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Pagina Estática
*/
?>

///Seu conteúdo
```

Salve no diretório do seu template.

Feito isso, entre no Admin do Wordpress, crie esta página que você precisa e, na opção `Modelo de Página`, deverá aparecer o modelo `Página Estática`. Pronto!

Comment: Na verdade, a pergunta procura exatamente evitar esta solução.